# Is there a way to work backwards using CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, border, hyperlink

I want to know if there is a way to work backwards in CSS.  What I mean is say I have a border around a div tag and then inside that div tag is a link that has a hover function.  Is there a way to change the border color on the div tag when that link is hovered or is this only achievable using jquery?

Comment: Technically, you are hovering over the div if you are hovering over the link...

Comment: But you are not always hovering over the link if hovering over the div..

Comment: Yes the div changes colors as I hover over it and then inside is a link.  I want that div to change colors as the link is hovered.

Answer (score 1):

That will be possible when the next CSS selectors specification is ready and implemented by the browsers. Then it will be possible to write something like:

```
!div a:hover { border-color: red; }
```

The current working draft proposal is here: http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-selectors4-20120823/#subject

Answer (score 0):

You can make the whole div hoverable:

```
.outer-class:hover {
  border-color: some-color;
}
```

Whereas `outer-class` is the class of the div.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is: No, there is no such way. Using jQuery to achive that is overkill yet and I would not recommend that. Instead refactor your markup and remember that you can access pseudo classes (:hover) not only for links (the days we support IE6 are definetly over, and even IE7 supports :hover on arbitrary elements iirc), so you could simply do:

```
div:hover {
    border-color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kind of possible. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/hL3Ta/

```
<div>
    <a href="#">Some link</a>
</div>
```

..

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    border:5px solid black;
}
div:hover {
    border: 5px solid red;
}

a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

As mentioned in other answers, the nature of the block model doesn't currently allow for selectors to operate in reverse. The pure CSS workaround is to use the pseudo-elements on containers that have the dimensions as your nested target.